# .NET core/Python Read first X lines from Azure Storage Blob

Tags: python, c#, .net-core, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I have a large blob which I need to extract the first few rows from. Can I do this without opening the entire file?

The file is in a known format (typically Excel, sometimes .csv or .tsv).

Just knowing if it is possible would be extremely helpful. I've obtained mixed answers, based on date, while searching MS and other forums. Thank you!

Comment: It's incredibly hard for us to say anything, without knowing the entire story. But that's irrelevant anyways, as Stack Overflow is not for asking/ answering feasibility questions

Comment: With that being said, probably not, unless you can run the code on the machine where the file is physically located at, then it'd be as easy as only reading the first X bytes of the `FileStream`

Comment: Using Oledb.  It doesn't open a file the same way you do from normal Open method so less memory is used.

Comment: I appreciate the comments. I'll keep the feasibility scope in mind for future questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a large blob which I need to extract the first few rows from.
> Can I do this without opening the entire file?

The answer is both yes and no. Yes, you can read partial contents however you can't read the first few lines.

Essentially Blob Storage Service allows you to perform a range read where you can specify the range of data (starting bytes and number of bytes to read) that you want to read. Once the range is specified in the request, Azure Storage will only return those bytes.

If you're using .Net SDK, please look at [`DownloadStreaming`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.specialized.blobbaseclient.downloadstreaming?view=azure-dotnet-preview&viewFallbackFrom=azure-dotnet#Azure_Storage_Blobs_Specialized_BlobBaseClient_DownloadStreaming_Azure_HttpRange_Azure_Storage_Blobs_Models_BlobRequestConditions_System_Boolean_System_Threading_CancellationToken_) method.